# calling webapi on client side (iphone/safari/chrome/IE) - right way to consume it?

Tags: iphone, ipad, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have created a webapi project that gets the media file from cdn network . in the project we verify the identity of files, change some content header value and return response as a HttpResponseMessage .

Client side , I have a test application where I am trying to access and play video files . client side code looks like this :

```
 <video controls autoplay name="media" height="360" width="220">
    <source src="http://localhost/api/media/test/filename.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>
</video>
```

my queston is , is this the right way to consume webapi directly to src tag. or i need to intitiate HttpClient on client side and call this webapi method . i searched on internet and see both kind of example . it's working fine in browsers but not working in iphone/ipad device . is it because of the way I am calling this ??

i'll appreicate your answer .

Comment: Are the files on the cdn network from untrusted sources? It can make a difference from a security standpoint.

Comment: it's not from untrusted source . at the same time in webapi method we have mechanism to verify files are not tempered. but yes, we change some httpHeaderInformation in file, content-Type and then returing the file as httprespnseMesage. not sure if it's make file untrusted or not. i can share the code if needed to ..